# how to load content from string into webView?

Tags: swift, webview

i save webView content into NSUserDefaults for offline use.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    let script = "document.documentElement.outerHTML.toString()"
    webView.evaluateJavaScript(script,completionHandler: { (out: Any?, error: Error?) in
        self.htmlContent = out as! String!
    })
}
```

What's way to load content from the htmlContent back into webView?

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
func loadHTMLString(_ string: String, 
        baseURL: URL?) -> WKNavigation?
```

so:

```
webView.loadHTMLString(self.htmlContent, baseURL: nil)
```

you can read more about this method: 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1415004-loadhtmlstring

and better will be to use `guard` instead force casting:

```
guard let htmlContent = out as? String else {
    return
}
self.htmlContent = htmlContent
```

Comment: So simply, thx, its works fine :) But there is a problem, in the output, the content does not look like the original (no markup of tables, fonts, etc.).
I think it's because I keep the content in the string.